# Fork oil spilled out. Rebound Damper Assembly is missing

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, shocks

I took my bike out of the car, and it spilled lots of oil from the fork when was on the tarmac, ( Manitou Six Elite 2002 ) through a screw-hole where the "Rebound Damper Assembly" is supposed to be. I searched my car and couldn't find the rebound damper assembly.

Oil fell out and this thing has gone:

[image]
[image]
My fork is trashed?
[image]

Fork service manual: https://www.manitoumtb.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/2002-Six-Owners-Manual.pdf

Specifically, I parked my car on uneven ground... I checked my phone: "is uneven ground *bad* for car suspension" the next day, I took out my bike. The bike suspension was broken. true story.

Comment: To remove rebound damper you'd have to unscrew it from the lowers at the bottom, remove the _compression_ damper through the top and slide the lowers off. Maybe you confused it with the compression damper? Can you post photos of your fork, both top and bottom of right leg?

Comment: Obviously, don't ride the bike at all in this state.    You need the missing part - check your car, and whereever else you've had the bike.  Think back, did it go CLUNK at any point?  Do you store the bike in a shared space - could someone have swiped the part?

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I added a photo of the right leg. I didn't hear it fall, the unwise thing is that I took off the front wheel, to fit in the car, and rested the fork brackets on the carpet of the car many times. Travel must have unscrewed the bolt, I don't know where it fell, I searched everywhere in the car. It didn't leak in the car, it leaked the moment the forks were emerged from the boot. Okay I won't ride it. I have searched all the car, I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Can you return to the place you unloaded the bike, and see if its on the ground anywhere?  Perhaps some kind soul moved it to a nearby fence post or other prominent spot.

Comment: To be frank - you're lucky it didn't fall out while you were riding.

Comment: I searched for 30 minutes in the car, around the car, under the car. So the strange thing is that the oil didn't spill in the car, and it could only be on a 1 meter straight line from where the fork was in the car to where the oil spilled on the limit of the boot. I couldn't believe it. I hope I can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [2004 Six service manual](http://www.spoke-n-word-cycles.com/TechnicalDocuments/Manitou/Manitou%202004/Answer%202004%20Six%20Service%20Manual.pdf), the rebound damper screws into lower casting, just like on (I think) any other Manitou fork:

> From the right leg dropout, use a 6mm hex wrench to turn the
>   compression rod counterclockwise until it screws into the casting. You
>   may have to apply pressure from the top of the comp rod using a long
>   6mm hex to start screwing it in.

For some mysterious reason, your lower rebound compression rod has unscrewed and let the oil in the leg out. Did your fork have a rebound adjustment knob down there when you put the bike in? Was it even there prior to that? If later, there's no "lost screw" to look for. And, as I said earlier, the rebound assembly won't fit through the hole.

At the very least, you'll need to perform a complete fork service, maybe ask your local bike shop if you aren't feeling up to task (oil can be super messy). If you did lose the knob, I'd try looking for a second-hand option or email Manitou and inquire about replacement part, their customer service is great.